# Recuperador dados de um objeto

Tags: java, swing

Tenho 2 telas no Swing, uma que chama um método e cadastra as informações em um array, e outro tela que deveria buscar uma dessas informações e exibir na mesma, o problema é que como os objetos são diferentes, eu não consigo pegar os dados do objeto que cadastra.

Tem alguma forma de conseguir pegar o endereço do objeto que cadastra para usar na tela de buscas e conseguir extrair as informações dessa array ou fazer alguma coisa do tipo?

OBS: tem que ser com array, não posso usar db ou arquivos externos.

Um exemplo de uma tela de Cadastro:

```
public void formularioCadastro() {

        Alunos cadastrarAlunos = new Alunos();
        // Cadastra os nomes numa Array
        cadastrarAlunos.setNome("Maria", 0); // Nome, posição da Array
        cadastrarAlunos.setNome("Lindovania", 1); // Nome, posição da Array
        cadastrarAlunos.setNome("Jose", 2); // Nome, posição da Array
        cadastrarAlunos.setNome("Josefina", 3); // Nome, posição da Array
        cadastrarAlunos.setNome("Maristela", 4); // Nome, posição da Array
}
```

Tela de Busca:

```
public void formularioBusca() {

        BuscarAluno buscarNome = new BuscarAluno();
        buscarNome.buscar("Jose");
}
```

O que acontece é o seguinte, se rodar esse código, ele vai dar NullPointerException, porque os dados cadastrados na "Tela de Cadastro" estão no objeto "cadastrarAlunos".Para poder buscar os valores que foram cadastrados lá, teria que usar o mesmo objeto, o que no caso, não é possível pois são duas telas(arquivos) diferentes.

Ai volta a pergunta lá de cima, tem como recuperar esses dados ou a referência do objeto pra fazer uso como descrevi acima?

Comment: Posta o código. Sem ele é como tentar plugar uma tomada num bloco de concreto.

Comment: Editei o post principal, com o exemplo!

Comment: Tem certeza que quer usar um array? Isso aí tá parecendo uma lista.

Comment: O que há na sua classe `Alunos` e na sua classe `BuscarAluno`? Como suas telas são instanciadas?

Comment: Patrick, não sei usar Listas e também nem posso, é um trabalho de faculdade.
Victor, na classe Alunos tem um método get e set, e na BuscarAluno um método que varre a array com um for e retorna se existe na array ou não. Ai seria apenas um exemplo, mas as telas do swing seria, um jFrame(Tela Inicial) que chama 2 JInternalFrame(Cadastrar e Buscar).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que vale unificar as suas classes `Alunos` e a sua classe `BuscarAluno`, pois ambas me parecem representar um mesmo conceito, que é o seu banco de dados de alunos, mesmo que esse banco de dados seja apenas um array na memória.

Feito isso, ambas as telas tem que usar a mesma instância do seu banco de dados (vamos dizer que seja a classe `Alunos`). A forma mais simples de fazer isso seria instanciá-la na tela principal e passá-la como parâmetro do construtor das suas classes que representam as telas de cadatsro e busca.

Se isto não estiver claro o suficiente, por favor, edite a sua questão colocando mais código, pois é difícil ajudá-lo sem tê-lo. Não dá para ficar adivinhando como é que o seu código está.